# how to set click counter in facebook audience network interstitial ad?

Tags: java, android, facebook, admob, facebook-audience-network

I use the below code to show FAN interstitial ads when clicking on `RecyclerView` item in my android app.
But if I implement this code not working.I want to show one item click one time show ads.Any help me please.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
            ImageView iv;
            TextView tv;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i = new Intent(JSONFeedActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                PostItem pi = filteredposts.get(getAdapterPosition());
                i.putExtra("title", pi.title);
                i.putExtra("link", pi.link);
                i.putExtra("desc", pi.desc);
                i.putExtra("image", pi.thumbnailUrl);
                startActivity(i);
                if (counter == 1) {
                    Log.d("log-", "INTERSTITIAL is loaded!");
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    }
                    counter = 1;
                } else {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your counter is always set to 1 while it is already 1.
You can do something like this.

http://www.hackerseve.com/how-to-implement-admob-s-interstitial-ad-the-right-way-in-android-apps/